A Story of Two Ants And The Pot of Sugar
There's a story about two ants who were searching for food. I've paraphrased it below.
They found a place where sugar was being prepared in a huge pot and ran towards it.
One of the ants jumped into the pot and thus turned into sugar.
The other one maintained a slight distance and kept drinking the sugar.
I heard it the first time from Sri Premanandji Maharaj (Radha Vallabhi) who resides in Vrindavan dham.
The second time I heard it from Sri M (Kriya Yoga teacher) who said that it was said by Guru Nanak - aound 27:00 in this video.
Is this or a similar analogy found in the shastra (Veda, Upanishad, Purana, Tantra, etc.)?
Thanks
